# Simplify a condition

Tags: c#

```
var objectA = new ObjectA();
var objectB = new ObjectB();

....

if(objectA!=null && objectB!=null){

//safely use objectA and objectB.. 
}
else{
 if(objectA==null&&objectB!=null){
 // safely use objectA but not objectB
 }
 if(objectA!=null&&objectB==null){
 //safely use objectB but not objectA
 }
 if(obectA==null&& objectB==null){
 // objects cannot be used.
 }
}
```

how can I simplify this condition?

Comment: you have 2 objects with 2 potential values (in this case), so you'll always need 2*2=4 conditions.  It can be rewritten a lot of ways, but not really simplified.

Comment: C#6 has null-coalescing operator `?`--might give it a try to see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

this seems a little easier to follow IMO

```
if(objectA != null){
    if(objectB != null){
        // safely use objectA or objectB
    }
    else{
        // safely use objectA but not objectB
    }
}
else if(objectB != null){
    // safely use objectB but not objectA

else{
    // do not use either
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there are exactly 4 possible cases you are interested in I would do a simple `if-else if-else if-else` and avoid any unneeded nesting.

```
if(objectA != null && objectB != null)
{    
    //safely use objectA and objectB.. 
}
else if(objectA == null && objectB == null)
{
    // objects cannot be used.
}
else if(objectB == null)
{
    //safely use objectA but not objectB
}
else
{
    // safely use objectB but not objectA
}
```

Also if you know which scenario is the most likely you should put that one first, then the second most likely and so on.  For instance if you know that most of the time nothing is `null` and `objectA` is less likely to be `null` than `objectB` you'd do the following.

```
if(objectA != null && objectB != null)
{    
    //safely use objectA and objectB.. 
}
else if(objectA != null && objectB == null)
{
    //safely use objectA but not objectB
}
else if(objectB != null)
{
    // safely use objectB but not objectA
}
else
{
    // objects cannot be used.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   if (objectA != null && objectB != null)
        {
            //safely use objectA and objectB.. 
        }
        else
        {
            if (objectA == null && objectB != null)
            {
                // safely use objectA but not objectB
            }
            else if (objectA != null && objectB == null)
            {
                //safely use objectB but not objectA
            }
            else
            {              
                // objects cannot be used.
            }
        }
```

Comment: this is exactly what the OP already has, just with better formatting

Comment: @dubstylee No, this uses `else if` and `else` which is slightly better.  Though the `else if` could just be `else if(objectA != null)` because we've covered the cases where `objectB` is not `null`

Comment: Do you see any better code here,I mean using less `if` and `else if`. they just made the code messy and hard to read. @dubstylee

Comment: Ah, I think I was not scrolling up all the way when I was comparing code. My bad.